# Why is the Machzor called a Machzor?

Tags: words, hebrew, prayer-book, etymology, chagim-holidays

The Siddur we use for Yom Tov is known as a Machzor. What does it mean and where did this originate?

Comment: "where did this originate" do you mean the word machzor, or the prayer-book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch in [OC 100](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=256) rules that prior to a holiday one must go over and prepare the text of the prayers so that he is familiar with them.

I suggest this is why holiday prayer books are called Machzor from the root Ch.Z.R. which can mean to review or to go over.

Answer (score 6):

> The word mahzor means "cycle" (the root Ħ-Z-R means "to return"). It is applied to the festival prayer book because the festivals recur annually.

from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machzor)

Comment: "Machzor" in modern Hebrew also refers to a woman's menstrual cycle.  So, when checking to make sure that everyone attending services has a prayer book, never ask a woman in Hebrew "?יש לך מחזור"  (Yes, this really happened.  Yes, all involved were quite embarrassed.)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in [yydl's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10476/1442), the Hebrew noun "מחזור" ("*machzor*") means "cycle" in English. This is the usage found in *Pirkei d'Rabbi Eliezer* ([ch. 6-8](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/pirkeyeliezer/pirkeyeliezer02.pdf)) and other midrashic literature.

According to the Hebrew Wikipedia article ["מחזור תפילה"](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%96%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94), citing Daniel Goldschmidt's [preface](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21241&st=&pgnum=12) to Shadal's *Introduction to the* Machzor *of the Community of Rome*, this term was used in medieval times to refer to prayer books that contained a comprehensive list of prayers for the entire cycle of the year (e.g. the 11th century [*Machzor Vitry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simhah_ben_Samuel_of_Vitry#The_Vitry_Machzor) composed by Rabbi Simcha ben Shmuel of [Vitry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitry-le-Fran%C3%A7ois)).

Eventually, standard prayer books (often including only the standard weekday and Sabbath prayers) became called "*siddurim*" due to the arrangement of the prayers contained therein, and the term "*machzor*" either became reserved as a reference to compilations of prayers for special holidays such as the High Holy Days (especially in Germany) or retained its original meaning as a comprehensive compilation of yearly prayers (such as in Italy and Livorno).

Comment: And siddur used to mean a halachic compendium.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. It and the other answers here are going to go very well in [*Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?*](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/and-revision-and-houses-of-prayer-and-tzedaka-distribute-the-goodness-of-mi-y).